# How do I insert blank columns based on certain conditions?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to insert certain number of blank columns.
For example, row 1 column 1 is Q1, and row 1 column 2 is Q2, thus I dont need to insert any blank column.

If  row  1 column 4 is Q5, row 1 column 3 is Q3, thus i want to insert (5-3-1) 1 blank column, a column to accommodate for Q4

Picture of the table is attached below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTpVH.jpg

Sorry this is my first time writing on VBA. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Updated**
Below is the error message displayed.

> Compile error: Expected array

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim lCol As Integer
Dim pos() As Long
Dim pos1() As Long
Dim strString() As String

lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lCol
     If Left(Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value, 1) = "Q" Then
            pos(i) = InStr(1, Cells(1,i), "Q") + 1
            pos1(i) = InStr(pos(i), Cells(1,i), "<")
            strString(i) = Mid(Cells(1,i), pos(i), pos1(i) - pos(i))
            If strString(i + 1) - strString(i) > 1 Then
                Columns(strString(i)+1:strString(i+1)-1).Insert 
                Shift:=xlToRight
            End If
        End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If Q7 occurs twice, then Q9 occurs 3 times, I just want to insert a blank column between to accommodate for column Q8.

Comment: Between Q6 and Q9 for example, I just need 2 blank columns for Q7,Q8

Comment: Thank you! I just changed from ActiveCell to Cells. I still need to configure on the dim

Answer (score 0):

You have declared pos, pos1 and strStringas Integers then in your code you are using them as Arrays: pos(i), pos1(i), and strString(i+1). That is why you are getting the compile error Expected Array.

Also, when adding rows you need to move from the bottom up or adding columns from right to left. your counter should go from lCol to 1 Step -1.

You need to fully qualify your objects as well. Cells with no qualifier for which sheet will use whatever sheet is the active sheet, not necessarily the one you want to affect.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific error, the variables `pos`, `pos1` and `strString` need to be declared as arrays as we store multiple values and not only a single one.
This could be done in several difference [ways](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_arrays.htm):

```
'Method 1 : Using Dim
Dim arr1()  'Without Size

'Method 2 : Mentioning the Size
Dim arr2(5)  'Declared with size of 5

'Method 3 : using 'Array' Parameter
Dim arr3
arr3 = Array("apple","Orange","Grapes")
```

I will use `Method 1`, and after I know how many columns we need, I will resize/define the array so it will look like `Method 2`.

`ActiveCell` will not work as it refer to a single selection, so we need to change that to a dynamic reference.

Since you will add columns, your "total" range will be change for each inserted column. So if you have 14 columns from the beginning, you might miss the last ones as your range will have increased. I therefore recommend to start from right and loop to the left.

I also automatically added the headers for the new inserted column. Thought it could be a nice feature.

This code is hopefully something that can help you along:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim lCol As Integer
Dim pos() 'Dim the variable as Array
Dim pos1() 'Dim the variable as Array
Dim strString() 'Dim the variable as Array
Dim i As Long 'Dim the variable i which will hold the position
Dim j As Long 'Dim the variable j which will loop for new inserted headers
Dim k As Long 'Dim the dummy variable k which will add one number for each empty header, between two quarters

    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find the last column to loop through
    ReDim pos(0 To lCol) 'When we know how many columns to loop through we can resize our array for the variable pos
    ReDim pos1(0 To lCol) 'Same logic as above
    ReDim strString(0 To lCol) 'Same logic as above

    For i = lCol + 1 To 1 Step -1 'Since we want to insert a new column our "complete range will change". Therefore we start backwards and to Column A
        If Left(Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value, 1) = "Q" Then 'Check if cell in row 1 starts with letter Q
            pos(i) = InStr(1, Cells(1, i), "Q") + 1 'Get position for Q and add 1
            pos1(i) = InStr(pos(i), Cells(1, i), "<") 'Get position for sign "<"
            strString(i) = Mid(Cells(1, i), pos(i), pos1(i) - pos(i)) 'Extract the difference between "pos" and "pos1" to get which quarter we are dealing with
            If ((strString(i + 1)) - strString(i)) > 1 And Not IsEmpty(strString(i + 1)) Then 'If the difference between cell "i +1" - cell "i" is larger than 1, and cell "i+1" is not empty, then..
                Columns(i + 1).Resize(, ((strString(i + 1)) - strString(i)) - 1).Insert '... We use the difference between the cells and then resize our range which we want to insert

                '### this part is only to create the header automatically, can be removed. ###
                If ((strString(i + 1)) - strString(i)) > 2 Then 'If the difference is larger than 2, it means that we need to insert at least 2 columns or more
                    k = 1 'Set dummy variable k to 1
                    For j = i + 1 To strString(i) + (((strString(i + 1)) - strString(i)) - 1) 'Loop through the new empty inserted columns and add quarter headers
                        Cells(1, j).Value = "Q" & strString(i) + k & "<>"
                        k = k + 1 'Add one quarter
                    Next j
                Else
                    Cells(1, i + 1).Value = "Q" & strString(i + 1) - ((strString(i + 1) - strString(i)) - 1) & "<>" 'Add Quarter headers if only one column was inserted
                End If
                '### --------------------------------------------------------------------- ###

            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Final result:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!:)

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid arrays:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim lCol As Long, i As Long
    Dim qCurrent As Long, qPreceeding As Long

    With Sheets(1) 'reference your sheet
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' start from referenced sheet row 1 last not empty column index
        Do While lCol > 1 ' start iterating from last column
            If Left(.Cells(1, lCol).Value, 1) = "Q" Then
                qCurrent = Val(Mid(.Cells(1, lCol).Value, 2)) ' get current column"Q" value
                qPreceeding = Val(Mid(.Cells(1, lCol - 1).Value, 2)) ' get preceeding column"Q" value

                If qCurrent > qPreceeding + 1 Then ' if current "Q" is not consecutive of preceeding one
                    .Cells(1, lCol).EntireColumn.Resize(, qCurrent - qPreceeding - 1).Insert ' insert columns
                    For i = 1 To qCurrent - qPreceeding - 1 'loop to recreate new headers
                        .Cells(1, lCol + i - 1).Value = "Q" & qPreceeding + i & "<>"
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            lCol = lCol - 1 ' step backwards
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!:) Ill make sure to understand code by code for my learning

Comment: you are welcome. If my answer solved your question you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you!